# how to call React hooks or modify state between separate functions in separate tsx files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 tsx files.  The first is called Stepper.tsx and it has a material UI stepper that shows which step of a form the user is on. The second is FormElements.tsx which contains the various forms that make up the steps.  I want to modify the stepper in Stepper.tsx depending on which form/panel is expanded and "active" in FormElements.tsx.

Here's how it looks in a browser so you get the gist of it:
[image]

The relevant Stepper.tsx code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Stepper.css';
import {
    BrowserView,
    MobileView,
} from "react-device-detect";
import StepperComponent from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

// Stepper on left rail
function getSteps() {
    return ['Personal', 'Biographic', 'Education', 'Experience', 'Licensure', 'Publications', 'Certify & Submit'];
}

function getStepContent(stepIndex: number) {
    switch (stepIndex) {
        case 0:
            return 'Contact Info, Address, Citizenship, Match Info, Etc.';
        case 1:
            return 'General, Self-Identification, Languages, Military, Etc.';
        case 2:
            return 'Higher Education, Medical Education, Etc.';
        case 3:
            return 'Training, Clinical, Teaching, Etc.';
        case 4:
            return 'State Medical Licenses, Etc.';
        case 5:
            return 'Publications, Etc.';
        case 6:
            return 'Review Your Application, Then Submit';
        default:
            return 'Unknown';
    }
}

export default function Stepper() {

    // stepper
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
    const steps = getSteps();

    return (

     <div>

        {/* Enables optimized view for desktop */}
        <BrowserView>

        {/* 
        #################################################################
        / The Stepper 
        #################################################################
        */}
        <div className="stepperContainer">
            <StepperComponent activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical" className="stepperComponent">
                {steps.map((label, index) => (
                    <Step key={label}>
                        <StepLabel className="stepperLabel">{label}</StepLabel>
                        <StepContent>
                            <Typography className="stepperContent">{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                        </StepContent>
                    </Step>
                ))}
            </StepperComponent>  
        </div>
        {/* 
        #################################################################
        / The Stepper 
        #################################################################
        */}

        </BrowserView>

         {/* Enables optimized view for mobile */}
         <MobileView>
             <div className="stepperContainer">
                  The application form.
             </div>
         </MobileView>
     </div>
  );
}
```

The relevant FormElements.tsx code is:

```
export default function FormElements() {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<string | false>('panel1');

    const handleChange = (panel: string) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, isExpanded: boolean) => {
        setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
    };


    return (

     <div>

        {/* Enables optimized view for desktop */}
        <BrowserView>

        <div>


            {/* 
            #################################################################
            The Collapsible Form 
            #################################################################
            */}

             <div className="formContainer">
                <div className="formElement1Container">

                {/* 
                #################################################################
                Form Section - Personal Information
                #################################################################
                */}
                    <ExpansionPanel
                                expanded={expanded === 'panel1' && Stepper.setActiveStep(2)}
                                onChange={handleChange('panel1')}
                                defaultExpanded
                    >
```

What I am doing in FormElements.tsx isn't working b/c they are broken out into different .tsx files and functions so just trying to figure out what the right way to do this is.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Pass a callback from the stepper to the formElements? If they are really distanced, then a context or greater app state (i.e. redux) may help.

Comment: Thanks Drew.  I've been playing with use-global-hook - https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8 - and it seems to be the best way I've found to do this.  I have the sample app working, going to try and apply it to my use case tomorrow.   Not sure if it's overkill, it seems there must be an easy way to do this "natively" but I'm pretty sure it will fit my need..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.

I used [use-global-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-global-hook) and it made it super easy.

After installing use-global-hook via

```
npm install -s use-global-hook
```

I created 2 new files in my /src/hooks directory:

**/src/hooks/storeMainExpansionState/store/index.js** holds the number of the step the user is on and is what the stepper will rely on to highlight the appropriate step now:

```
import React from "react";
import useGlobalHook from "use-global-hook";

import * as actions from "../act";

const initialState = {
    counter: 0
};


const useGlobal = useGlobalHook(React, initialState, actions);

export default useGlobal;
```

**/src/hooks/storeMainExpansionState/act/index.js** holds the function which my form and expansion panels call to set this value:

```
export const setCounter = (store,step) => {
    var counter = 0;
    var step = step;

    if (step == 'panel1') {
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (step == 'panel2') {
        counter = 1;
    }
    if (step == 'panel3') {
        counter = 2;
    }
    if (step == 'panel4') {
        counter = 3;
    }
    if (step == 'panel5') {
        counter = 4;
    }
    if (step == 'panel6') {
        counter = 5;
    }
    if (step == 'panel7') {
        counter = 6;
    }

  store.setState({ counter });
};
```

**In my existing FormElements.tsx file** I made the following modifications:

added this import

```
import useGlobal from "../../../hooks/storeMainExpansionState/store";
```

added this to my default function:

```
const [globalState, globalActions] = useGlobal();
```

added this to my function that fires off when a panel is expanded:

```
 globalActions.setCounter(panel);
```

**In my existing Stepper.tsx file** I made the following modifications:

I added this import:

```
import useGlobal from "../../../hooks/storeMainExpansionState/store";
```

I added this declaration to the default function:

```
const [globalState, globalActions] = useGlobal();
```

I added this to where I return the stepper component and set the active step:

```
<StepperComponent activeStep={globalState.counter} orientation="vertical" className="stepperComponent">
```

Now it works, and the stepper (Stepper.tsx) highlights the appropriate active step based on which panel is expanded in the main form (FormElements.tsx) like this:

[image]

And the cool part is now I have the step the user is on stored globally so any other new features that need it can simply import and call the global variable like this:

import:

```
import useGlobal from "../../../hooks/storeMainExpansionState/store";
```

declare:

```
const [globalState, globalActions] = useGlobal();
```

call:

```
{globalState.counter}
```

Easy peasy.